# unable to do inline editing with php code igniter and jquery. Not able to update table values in the database

Tags: php, jquery, angularjs, ajax, codeigniter

this is my edit_table.php in which dynamic table is generated and by on click function i try to update database.

```
    <script>
function table_edit(btn)
{
    var id=btn.id;
    if(btn.value=="Edit")
    {
         document.getElementById('college_id'+id).setAttribute("contenteditable" , "true");
        document.getElementById('name'+id).setAttribute("contenteditable" , "true");

        //document.getElementById('university_id'+id).removeAttribute("Readonly");
        document.getElementById('university_id'+id).setAttribute("contenteditable" , "true");
        document.getElementById(id).value="Save";
        return false;


    }

    if(btn.value=="Save")
    {
        document.getElementById('name'+id).removeAttribute("contenteditable");
        document.getElementById('college_id'+id).removeAttribute("contenteditable");

    // document.getElementById('university_id'+id).setAttribute("Readonly" , "readonly");
    document.getElementById('university_id'+id).removeAttribute("contenteditable");
    document.getElementById(id).value="Edit";   
    var newuniversity_id=document.getElementById('university_id'+id).innerHTML;
    var newcollege_id=document.getElementById('college_id'+id).innerHTML;
    var newname=document.getElementById('name'+id).innerHTML;
    alert(newname+"  "+newcollege_id+"  "+newuniversity_id+" "+id);
  var dataString = 'name1=' + name + '&university_id=' + newuniversity_id + '&college_id=' + newcollege_id + '&id=' + id;
  $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "update_table_data",
data: dataString,
success: function(html) {
alert("ajax calling done");
}
});
        return true;

    }

}



  function table_update(){

    //document.getElementById("edit_rows").value="Save"
    alert("Working!");
}
</script>
<?php 
function test()
{
    echo "<script>alert('hello');</script>";
    } ?>

<div id="page-content-wrapper">



    <div class="container-fluid">

    <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> <span>Menu</span></a>


      <div class="content-block">



<div class="login-sign forgot_pass login forgot text-center">

        <!-- <form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>edit_table" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"> -->
            <div class="login-signup-head">Edit Table</div>
<table>
<tbody>
     <thead>
          <tr class="tredit">
            <!-- <th width="10"></th> -->
            <th> Id </th>
            <th > University Id </th>
            <th > Name </th>
            <th > College Id </th>
            <th width="100"> </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

                      <?php 
     foreach($student_data as $row){

      ?>
        <tr class="tredit" id="row_edit"> 
            <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
            <td id="university_id<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" ><?php echo $row['university_id']; ?></td> 
            <td id="name<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"  ><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td> 
            <td id="college_id<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"  > <?php echo $row['college_id']; ?></td> 
            <td><input type='button' class='editable' onclick=" return table_edit(this)" value='Edit' id= "<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
            <input type='button' class='tabledelete' onclick="table_update()" value='Delete' ></td> 
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
?>
 </div>
   </div>
   </div>
<!--    </form> -->
   </div>  
</div>
</tbody>
     </table>
```

and this is the route

$route['update_table_data'] = 'home/update_table';

and the following functions are for fetching the data as well as updating the data.

```
    public function tableedit(){



          if($this->session->userdata('university_id')){



              $user_id =  $this->session->userdata('university_id');
            $data['user_id'] = $user_id;
            $data['student_data'] = $this->home_model->table_data($user_id);

              $this->load->view('home/new-header',$data);

               $this->load->view('home/left_university_sidebar',$data);
               $this->load->view('edit_table',$data);

               $this->load->view('home/footer');

          } else {
              $data['error'] = 'Table Cannot be viewed!';
              $this->load->view('home/header');
              $this->load->view('edit_table');
              $this->load->view('home/footer');

          }

      }

       public function update_table() { 
             if($this->session->userdata('university_id')){

           if($this->input->server("REQUEST_METHOD") === "POST"){

              $university_id=$_POST['university_id'];
              $college_id=$_POST['college_id'];
              $id=$_POST['id'];
              $name=$_POST['name'];
              $this->home_model->update_table($university_id,$college_id,$name,$id);
             }
       }
}
```

and finally this is the model for update query.

```
public function update_table($university_id,$college_id,$name,$id) {

    $data = array('University Id' => $university_id,  'name' => $name, 'College Id' => $college_id);

    $this->db->where('id', $id);

    $this->db->update('college', $data);

}
```

[editable table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dPcP.png)

[edit values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IN5Wg.png)

but when i save and refresh the page, no change occur in the table.
my issue is database is not updated when i update it from save button.

Comment: You need to narrow down the problem (and code...), I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Just a second. Let me modify my code. Sorry for delay!

Comment: Please have a look and the discription and go through it. So issue is i have a table in html and i have bascially fetched its value from db & i have made it editable but not able to update it in the db. Can you help me in this context?

Answer (score 0):

first of all :

Formatting your code , that must be clean and easily readable

for your ajax call you dont need use routed url , it work at background, you can use like this :

put : `<script>var base_url='<?php echo base_url(); ?>'</script>`

in your header menu , or upper place that you use in your theme.

then make ajax call like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: base_url+"youController/yourAction",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(html) {
            alert("ajax calling done");
        }
    });
```